# Why my program is closing when I am using Slider in pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Why my program is closing when I am using Slider in pyqt5? It starts normal but after using Slider it close. I have to change size of circle in first window by using Slider from second window. This is my full code, beacuse I don't know what could be wrong.
[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class ThirdWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        sld.setRange(0, 100)
        sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        sld.setPageStep(5)

        sld.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

        self.label = QLabel('0', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.label.setMinimumWidth(80)

        hbox.addWidget(sld)
        hbox.addSpacing(15)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(600, 60, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('QSlider')
        self.show()

    def updateLabel(self, value):
        self.label.setText(str(value))
        self.parentWidget().radius = value
        self.parentWidget().repaint()


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialogi")
        self.w = ThirdWindow()
        actionFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("Dialog")
        action = actionFile.addAction("Zmień tło")
        action1 = actionFile.addAction("Zmień grubość koła")
        action1.triggered.connect(self.w.show)
        self.setGeometry(100, 60, 300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: Green")
        self.radius = 100  # add a variable radius to keep track of the circle radius

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.gray, 8, Qt.SolidLine))
        # change function to include radius
        painter.drawEllipse(100, 100, self.radius, self.radius)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Run the code in a console so you can see the traceback. Probably the issue is that `parentWidget()` is `None`.

Comment: console show me this ```Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Comment: @ResCrove it seems unlikely that the console shows **only** that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parentWidget` allows access to a widget declared as parent *for Qt*.

Creating an object using `self.w = ...` doesn't make that object a child of the parent (`self`), you are only creating a reference (`w`) to it.

If you run your program in a terminal/prompt you'll clearly see the following traceback:

```
Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'radius'
```

The `NoneType` refers to the result of `parentWidget()`, and since no parent has been *actually* set, it returns `None`.

While you *could* use `parentWidget` if you correctly set the parent for that widget (by adding the parent to the widget constructor, or using `setParent()`), considering the structure of your program it wouldn't be a good choice, and it's usually better to avoid changes to a "parent" object directly from the "child": the signal/slot mechanism of Qt is exactly intended for the modularity of Object Oriented Programming, as a child should not really "care" about its parent.

The solution is to connect to the slider *from* the "parent", and update it from there.

```
class ThirdWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        # make the slider an *instance member*, so that we can easily access it
        # from outside
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        # ...


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.w.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)

    def updateLabel(self, value):
        self.radius = value
        self.update()
```

You obviously need to remove the `valueChanged` connection in the `ThirdWindow` class, as you don't need it anymore.
Also note that you rarely need `repaint()`, and `update()` should be preferred instead.

Comment: I change this as you tell me and now i have got error TypeError: updateLabel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'       this is my code https://justpaste.it/8n0ol

Comment: @ResCrove if you use a pastebin service, ensure that it uses monospaced fonts and correctly displays indentation. Anyway, from the look at that error, you probably put the new `updateLabel` function in the wrong indentation level. And you are still trying to access `parentWidget()`. Please, don't just copy and paste, try to **understand** what the provide code does.

Comment: updateLabel is expecting a the `value` parameter. change `self.w.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.updateLabel)` to `self.w.slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda :self.updateLabel(X))`. `X` being the value you want to be displayed.

Comment: @RMRiver No. Please check the documentation before commenting: [`valueChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) already sends an integer as argument.

Comment: @ResCrove after reviewing again your code, you're trying to use `addWidget()` with `self.updateLabel()`, which doesn't make any sense: `addWidget()` requires a widget argument, and `updateLabel()` doesn't return any (obviously, since it's not it's purpose). You probably wanted to use `hbox.addWidget(self.slider)`. Again, please be more careful when you write code, and always check the full traceback of exceptions, then try to understand their reason. I'd have noticed the error earlier if you used an appropriate pastebin service, so always consider this for future reference.

Comment: @ResCrove: To get the code in your justpaste link to work you need to change `hbox.addWidget(self.updateLabel())` to `hbox.addWidget(self.slider)` and remove the last to lines (i.e. the ones starting with `self.parentWidget()`) from `ThirdWindow.updateLabel`.

Comment: @ResCrove you **REALLY** need to read and understand the suggestions that are given to you.